# Restrict user's ftp acces to specific folder with vsftpd

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I trying to restrict all users that is created to /var/www, but each user must be able to be restricted to any subdirectory. For example:
user test1 restricted to /var/www/
user test2 restricted to /var/www/somefolder/
user test3 restricted to /var/www/somefolder2/something
and so on. What is best way to implement it?

Comment: Read https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html - what makes you think this is possible?

Comment: I not sure if it works, but after additional hour of googling going to test option just use chroot, and for user just change home directory into directory I want to allow him to access with usermod -d. Gonna try that tomorow